# Python: How to extend a class?

Tags: python, inheritance, extends

So, I really want to add on a few new methods to `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`s. For example, I want a method called `.idx`:

```
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.idx(self, rows, cols):
    return self.iloc[rows].loc[cols]
```

Is this possible? I'm not sure what the syntax should be - the class already exists from a library, so I can't just put the function inside the class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually really easy in Python. While I would recommend inheriting from DataFrame, as MeetTitan answered, sometimes that won't work, but you can just add on functions like this:

```
class Abc(object):
    pass

def new_funct(self):
    print 1234

Abc.instance_funct = new_funct
a = Abc()
a.instance_funct()
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you not extend your `DataFrame`, inheriting all of its functions, and having the freedom to then define your own, on top?

In python it would look something like:

```
class ExtendedDataFrame(DataFrame):
    ...
```

Then, simply use an instance of `ExtendedDataFrame`, instead of `DataFrame`, for your extra goodies.

I also suggest taking a look at [this tutorial covering inheritance.](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/.)

Also be sure to check out your version of python's implementation of `super()`, if you're trying to override functions of the super (parent) class.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods) is a SO question with great information regarding `super()`, because I'm noticing the tutorial I linked only briefly covers `super()`, and in the comments no less.